# how to send email using web form for marketers 2.5 in sitecore mvc..?

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

i'm using web form for marketers 2.5 in sitecore mvc project, i successfully design form but on submit button i'm getting an error, i'm not able to figure out why this error comes please anyone help me to understand the cause of this error, error is saying :

```
 "The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long."
```

my configuration for this is as:

```
 <add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://myServer_Name/DncMvc_Analytics" />
 <add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_live" />
 <add name="tracking.history" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_history" />
 <add name="reporting" connectionString="user id=sa;password=simple;Data Source=myServer_Name\unicolumn;Database=DncMvc_Analytics" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try 2 things:

first: Change the web.config to increase the "maxQueryString"

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="#" maxQueryStringLength="#" />
```

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxUrl="#" maxQueryString="#" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

if the above doesn't work, you can enable the Anonymous Authentication within the IIS.

Comment: can you please share your web.config (after removing any sensitive data).

Comment: for testing i'm using only four fields for sending email message, it doesn't work using web form for marketers in sitecore MVC